# VBA excel compare Tables

Tags: excel, vba, compare

i have Table_1, Table_2, Table_3 and Table_Together. From Table_1, 2 and 3 i will get data from Column at A10 till end and also column at C10 and at E10 till end. My Target is to put all the Table information in Table_Together among each other also at Row 10.

Thank for supporting me

Comment: Can you show some data of what you already tried?

Comment: Thats my basic code for the problem

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want but try this

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Makro1()

    Dim i As Integer, r As Long, n As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Dim iLastRow As Long, iTargetRow As Long

    Dim dict As Object, key As String
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set ws = Worksheets("Table_Together")

     'list of existing records
    iTargetRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    For r = 10 To iTargetRow
        key = Trim(ws.Cells(r, "C"))
        If Len(key) > 0 Then
            dict(key) = r
        End If
    Next
    If iTargetRow < 9 Then iTargetRow = 9

    For i = 1 To 3
       Set ws1 = Worksheets("Table_" & i)
       iLastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row

       For r = 10 To iLastRow
           key = Trim(ws1.Cells(r, "E"))
           ' check not existing then copy
           If Not dict.exists(key) Then
                iTargetRow = iTargetRow + 1
                ws1.Cells(r, "A").Copy ws.Cells(iTargetRow, "A")
                ws1.Cells(r, "C").Copy ws.Cells(iTargetRow, "B")
                ws1.Cells(r, "E").Copy ws.Cells(iTargetRow, "C")
                n = n + 1
           End If
       Next r
    Next i
   
    MsgBox n & " rows added to " & ws.Name, vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much, thats what i mean. The problem here is that you have to check the value before you put the Data in Table_Together. If you dont check, the dat will be filled in Table_together twice oder more

Comment: @Harry How would you identify duplicate records, is there one column that is key ie unique id for that row.

Comment: Yes. In every Table in column E is a id number. And IF the id number in Table_Together is available, the column does not copy and destinate in Table together anymore from the other Table

Comment: @Harry OK, see update, This copies single rows if not already on Table_Together sheet. You can switch screen updating off/on to speed it up if required.

Comment: @Harry one more question, if i delete a column in other tables which containd the id and want to update the together_table how can i implement that? I thin its easier to say that all information in table_together should delet and fill it new? Thanks

Comment: @Harry Do you mean delete a row ? Yes easiest way is delete all and rerun. There is another way if you have a large number of rows and only want to delete a few.

Comment: Yes i mean i delete a row in table one, the go to table_together and run your code. Then the deleted information from table one will not delete in table_together. So i have to implement in your code that if the code will run, delete the page table_together.